# Do you need to hold concentration on a spell when you cast it with a spell scroll?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, concentration, out-of-the-abyss

I'm currently running *Out of the Abyss*, and my group is about to encounter a mage with a description that says

> If the characters become hostile, [the mage] orders
>   them to depart, lest they provoke the wrath of his
>   all-powerful master. If attacked, he uses his globe of
>   invulnerability scroll, casts fly on himself, and flies into
>   the chasm.

Both spells are concentration spells so I'm not sure if this is an error in the module, if you don't need concentration for scrolls, or if I read the paragraph wrong and he just uses the scroll first, runs away, and then proceeds to cast fly and fly away.

So my question is: Do I need to hold concentration for concentration spells cast with a spell scroll?

Comment: This is a mistake the published adventures make a ***lot***.

Comment: Simple fix, just make the "casts fly on himself" instead "quaffs a potion of fly"... potions don't require concentration. Doesn't really answer the question, just fixes the disparity in the rules for you as a DM.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## Yes

From the general rules on [casting spells from magic items](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/magic-items#Spells), my emphasis added:

> Some magic items allow the user to cast a spell from the item. The spell is cast at the lowest possible spell level, doesn't expend any of the user's spell slots, and requires no components, unless the item's description says otherwise. The spell uses its normal casting time, range, and duration, and the **user of the item must concentrate if the spell requires concentration**. Many items, such as potions, bypass the casting of a spell and confer the spell's effects, with their usual duration. Certain items make exceptions to these rules, changing the casting time, duration, or other parts of a spell.

There's nothing in the description of a [spell scroll](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/spell-scroll) that makes an exception.

In terms of how that should impact roleplaying the character, I'm not familiar with the adventure but it sounds to me like it is just presenting two main options for getting away and trying to avoid combat, so just keep them in mind as possibilities even though you can't really use both at once.