# Do the effects of spells granted by items require concentration?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, concentration

Casting or duplicating an entire spell from an item requires concentration; this makes sense, no confusion there. However, concentration for gaining or duplicating the **effect** of a spell that normally would require concentration appears unclear. This is not to be confused with a spell-like effect, such as the *potion of flying* which grants flying independent of the *fly* spell. In that example you are not gaining the effect of a spell, it is a spell-like effect.

The *potion of speed* explicitly says you don't need to concentrate despite *haste* normally needing concentration:

> When you drink this potion, you gain the effect of the *haste* spell for 1 minute (no concentration required).

The *potion of mind reading* does not have the same concentration clause seen in the *potion of speed*, even though *detect thoughts* also requires concentration:

> When you drink this potion, you gain the effect of the *detect thoughts* spell (save DC 13).

### If an item grants/duplicates a spells effect and not a spell-like effect, does the spell effect require concentration?

Comment: Related (though none are about potions): "[Do you need to hold concentration on a spell when you cast it with a spell scroll?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/156491)" and "[Is summoning an air elemental with the Censer of Controlling Air Elementals still a concentration spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/167464)" and "[Do magic item spells require concentration?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/99199)"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126735/discussion-between-codex-and-nautarch).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### There is no difference between duplicating the effects of a spell and duplicating a spell

This stems from a natural English reading of the words, a spell *is* its effects. I personally would see no difference between an item that duplicates *detect thoughts* and an item that duplicates the effects of *detect thoughts*. If the rules had wanted these to be markedly differently things I feel there would have been some general rule about spells / spell effects being duplicated stating that these are in fact different things. Lacking such a rule, I would conclude that these are identical.

---

I believe this is further supported by the fact that some, but not all, features that duplicate the effects of something include the line "no concentration required". If this was *always* the case, then there would be no reason to include such a line. An example of such a phrase is the potion of growth  or the potion of speed:

> When you drink this potion, you gain the "enlarge" effect of the enlarge/reduce spell for 1d4 hours (no concentration required).

> When you drink this potion, you gain the effect of the haste spell for 1 minute (no concentration required).

The fact that these explicitly call out the fact that concentration is *not* required leads me to assume that without this phrase concentration *would* be required. Therefore, duplicating an effect of a spell is the same as duplicating a spell, at least when it comes to the concentration requirement.

---

Another supporting piece of evidence is the Sage Advice Compendium which states:

> Q. If a potion doesn’t duplicate a spell, does it require concentration?
>
> A. A potion’s effect requires concentration only if its description says so or if it duplicates a spell that requires concentration.

As far as I can find, *every* potion that duplicates a spell has the wording of duplicating a spell's effects. Thus, this answer *must* be about those sorts of potions, otherwise it would be talking about an item that doesn't even exist. From this we can conclude that duplicating a spell is the same as duplicating an effect (or the effects) of a spell, and if the spell requires concentration, so too do the duplicated effects.